# redirect_to out of an iframe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

i have a rails app which has a form that renders in an iframe, and from the create action i would like to `redirect_to` out of the iframe and re-render the whole page rather than in the iframe.

i was curious what ideas are out there to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it! you have to replace the redirect_to with:

```
render :text => "<script>parent.location.href='/cms';</script>"
```

Comment: wont work, results in Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the redirect_to method won't be able to be aware of the iframe you're in and will instead have to be done through some javascript

You might be able to submit your form, via javascript, to the parent window by serializing the form fields.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.reload()` after submitting your form via AJAX?