# Ruby/Rails - Open a URL From The Controller In New Window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in my applications controller and I have a url string.  How do I tell the app to open the url in the browser in a new window.  Is there a way to set the target to blank?

For example

```
def link
  @url = 'www.google.com'
  ****??? Open @url ?? *** with target blank?
end
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685988/2917523 if you need to open a url in the _parent_ window from the controller--it's not ideal, but it's possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not possible to do directly from the controller. Using `redirect_to @url` has the effect of opening an URL in the same "window", as it simply sends a HTTP redirect instruction back to the browser. `redirect_to` is not capable of opening new windows. The controller resides on the server side, and opening a new window belongs to the client side.

Some options:

a) render a link with `<%= link_to 'Google', 'google.com', :target => '_blank' %>` or `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>` which the user can click on in a new view

b) use JavaScript to open the link automatically, but beware that browsers may treat this as a popup and block it

By combining these options you can open links in new window for browsers/users who allow it, and fall back to a regular URL in case that didn't work.

Comment: Just a normal link, i.e. <%= link_to 'Google', 'http://www.google.com', :target => '_blank' %> or <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>

Comment: Why not changing your answer?

Answer (score 5):

As the others point out, you can't (and shouldn't) do this in the controller. In the view you can use

```
<%= link_to @url, :target => "_blank" %>
```

Comment: hard to do this when it's form based and forms don't read anchor submissions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not that you **CAN'T** do it, it's just kind of a convoluted process.  I did this in a project I'm working on.  Basically, it's a mixture of Rails goodness and Javascript.  I simply passed a flash notice on creation of an instance, and then used a script to set that flash notice equal to a js variable, and a redirect_url.  If that particular flash notice pops up on that page, it redirects in the js script.  Like I said, it's **hack hack hack**, but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in rails, because your script is being executed on a server.
Use Javascript to work with browser on the client side.